# equivalent of jquery's event.type for node.js EventEmitter?

Tags: jquery, node.js

Does node.js have an equivalent of jquery's event.type method, i.e. something that gives the name of the event in the form of a string?

I've tried event.type but it hasn't worked for me so far...

Comment: What library are you using to handle events? Node.js doesn't have the DOM, so there is no event out of the box.

Comment: i mean events i create myself using the node.js eventemitter class

Comment: Check out [EventEmitter2](https://github.com/hij1nx/EventEmitter2), looks like it adds `this.event` to handlers that give you that info. (especially since it does wildcard and namespaced events)

Comment: thanks @dominic i've seen this on github, but since i'm just looking for a little hack to save 20 lines of code, i don't want to add 500 lines to get it to work ;)

Comment: Event.type is because of the Dom.  EventEmitter is much more bare bones.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a little wrapper function that gives you the name

```
 EventEmitter.prototype.addNamedListener = function(event, handler){
      return this.addHandler(function(x){
          handler({ event: event, data: x });
      });
 };
```